# AngularJS: selecting option from dropdown menu

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

Here is my code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="author" ng-options="author as author.fullname for author in authors" ng-model="author" ng-required="true"></select>
```

How would I change selected value from controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the `$scope.author` to whatever `author` you want, for example:

```
$scope.author = $scope.authors[2];
```

Here is an example [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/vegedadibe/edit?html,js,output)

Or look up the author some how (by name, id?) and set the `$scope.author` or whatever to that value.

Answer (score 3):

Angular works on "2-way binding". `ng-model="author"` binds your dropdown to  `$scope.author` so a change in either the dropdown or the controller will reflect on both places, hence the binding. 
So from your ng-options I'm assuming you have an array called authors of type author so in your controller simply

```
$scope.author = $scope.authors[0];
```

Remember that in the controller you need the `$scope.` before the variable and in the html ng-model or other ng directives you do not need the $scope. prefix